# where is the FBSDKShareDialog shareFromViewController method

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-share

download the latest Facebook SDK and followed the Document:

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developers.facebook.com"];
[FBSDKShareDialog shareFromViewController:self
                              withContent:content
                                 delegate:nil];
```

But there is a issue, no shareFromViewController method ! 
There is only has showFromViewController method, It can't do the share job,where is the share method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no shareFromViewController method in SDK for sharing.It's the showFromViewController method used for sharing.

```
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                                 withContent:tempContent
                                    delegate:self];
```

OR

```
FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
shareDialog.delegate=self;
shareDialog.fromViewController = self;
shareDialog.shareContent = content;
[shareDialog show];
```

//Delegate methods

```
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results{

}
 - (void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer{

}

- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
NSLog(@"%@",error);
}
```

Comment: showFromViewController  could send out a message? I tried it, it just show it and not send it to facebook.

Comment: then implement the delegate methods of FBSDKSharingDelegate and see the error